# HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

**This is persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="com.wic.jpa" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">  

        <class>com.udemy.jpa.Student</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />

            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/udemy? 
             serverTimezone=UTC" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.user" value="wic" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="wic" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>

            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="use_sql_comments" value="true" />

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**This is Student.java with entities**

```
package com.udemy.jpa;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="STUDENT")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="age")
    private int age;

    public Student(){

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }



}
```

**This is App.java with main**

```
package com.udemy.jpa;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = 
        Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("com.wic.jpa");
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

        Student s = new Student();
        s.setAge(25);
        s.setName("Ali");

        entityManager.persist(s);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

        entityManager.close();
        entityManagerFactory.close();

    }

}
```

**This is pom.xml file**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.udemy.jpa</groupId>
  <artifactId>FirstJPA</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is simple project to just create the table in database and insert the value into it using java, jdbc, jpa, hibernate. in Student class, i created entities and through that i create table and insert id, name and age. App class in which there is main method and a connection with database. I am new to this technology and didn't figure out the problem. Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Well what is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1V3o4TwjTOC_tSx6w3gQR002uVhO9-U2f

Comment: This is the link of the image of errors.